# Select every element that is not inside another element

Tags: jquery, css, dom, jquery-selectors

```
<img src="xxx" alt="xxx" title="xxx">
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="xxx"><img src="xxx" alt="xxx" title="xxx"></a>
</div>
```

I need to write a jQuery selector, that will select ONLY images with title attributes that are OUTSIDE the .buttons div. I know that to select images with title attributes I need to use something like this:

```
$("img[title]")
```

I know that there is something like :not() selector in jQuery, but I can't find the way to combine them together to achieve that exact result.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the result set then filter it using [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/), like this:

```
$("img[title]").not(".buttons img")
```

Or filter in the same selector using [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) (but this is *probably* a bit slower in older browsers), like this:

```
$("img[title]:not(.buttons img)")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without repeating the original selector (' img') part? I'm trying to look for errors not inside `.container-to-exclude`, and the errors can be several selectors, so I have them separated by commas, like `.Error, .Errors, .Warning`, and I don't want to have to say `$('.Error, .Errors, .Warning').not('.container-to-exclude .Error, .container-to-exclude .Errors, .container-to-exclude .Warning')`.

Comment: @jbyrd you can use `' *'` instead of `' img'`